# Multiple iCalendar VEvents or VTODOs for the same meeting

Tags: java, calendar, icalendar

My application needs to have a feature which would allow the creation of sort of like a project, where you put the total number of hours you need to work on it, the start date, the end date and how long each activity takes(additional constraints might be included as well).

What is the best way to create multiple VEvents according to those constraints with an option to change those VEvents? Also what's the best method to check the current iCalendar if the date is busy or not? Can I somehow retrieve all the busy dates from ics file and then just kind of check if the time gap is free or busy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, projects are described in terms of tasks ([VTODO](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.2)) instead of events. See http://www.calconnect.org/7_things_tasks.shtml for an introduction on tasks. This document also describes how tasks can be grouped together.

The second part of your question is a bit fuzzy. With a library like ical4j, you can make freebusy requests within a stream of vtodos. The other option would be to rely on a CalDAV server to store those.

Comment: in the document that you shared, there is no explanation how to create groups of VTODOs for a single project. I need to create those VTODOs or VEvents in the gaps of the specified time period every day until the number of total hours required is reached. I have to also have a way to move each of them in case something urgent comes up, I might just use a method of deleting everything and running the scheduling again, but then other days would be affected as well, so I would like to avoid that.